# SCDF Stream deployment disable random app name prefix

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Deploying stream (app) on spring cloud data flow 2.1.2 on PCF.

Can't get the generated random app prefix to go away.

Tried options during stream deployment :

deployer.*.cloudfoundry.enableRandomAppNamePrefix=false

Tried passing the following env variables to skipper-server

```
SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_STREAM_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: false
SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: false
```

Tried passing the following env variables to dataflow-server :

SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_STREAM_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: false
    SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: false

SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_STREAM_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: false

Thoughts ?

Comment: Hi, The properties look correct except `SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_STREAM_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX` as the key `stream` is not applicable to task platform property. I don't see any issues with the Skipper and Deployer properties as well. Can you check if those environment properties are indeed applied by checking the cf env on SCDF server?

Comment: OK, looks like that property is set on the scdf-server (not skipper server)

cf env scdf-server

..
SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_STREAM_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: false
..

But no luck. Still generating  random prefix.

Comment: Like I mentioned, the property `SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_STREAM_ENABLE_RANDOM_APP_NAME_PREFIX: false` is wrong as it is a task platform property and you are trying to apply it for the streams. You need to set either the Skipper or Deployer properties for the streams.

Comment: OK, took out that property and now just trying with the deployer properteis :
deployer.*.cloudfoundry.enableRandomAppNamePrefix=false

No luck.
The other related property : 
deployer.*.cloudfoundry.appNamePrefix
does not seem to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The correct environment property to set at the Skipper server side is:

`SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ACCOUNTS[default]_DEPLOYMENT_ENABLERANDOMAPPNAMEPREFIX: false`